# Print out recaptcha webform verification

Tags: 7

I created a webform-form-230.tpl to readjust the webfrom layout.

```
<div class="one_half">
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['name']); ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['e_mail']); ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['subject']); ?>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['date']); ?>       
</div>
<div class="one_half last">
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['message']); ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

I added [recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module.
How do I add recaptcha script in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for adding in temlate.php or in custom module for adding captcha.

```
if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_form_id')) {
        $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
            '#type' => 'captcha',
            '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
        );
    }
```

Also refer https://www.drupal.org/node/1254710 link.

One module is there you can check [CAPTCHA Webform Bridge](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha_webform).
This is a simple module that automatically set (or unset) CAPTCHA challenges to webforms.